# How to parse JSON having different keys in each array element using POJO classes in android

Tags: java, android, json, pojo

I have this response coming from server. I want to parse that using pojo classes. I have created pojo classes having setter and getter methods which holds values.But the logic which I am using is not working properly.While I'm printing values it was not returning values exactly.

Response:

```
{
        "code":200,
        "status":"ok",
        "message":"Promotions feed.",
        "data":{
        "feed":[
        {
        "id":0,
        "businessId":0,
      "photoUrl":"https:\/\/d1e6yi6s3cx2ur.cloudfront.net\/videos\/0\/8b84c9c1-50ed-4e93-9785-797bbf2be667.png",
        "videoUrl":"https:\/\/d1e6yi6s3cx2ur.cloudfront.net\/videos\/0\/_464b2fb6-ede6-403f-b6ae-1666c9504337.mov",
        "isNew":true,
        "type":"news"
        },
        {
        "id":198,
        "specialType":"limited",
        "name":"Big Data Shoes!",
        "description":"Get them now while you can. They're dangerous!",
        "start":"2017-06-04 14:59:01Z",
        "end":"2018-01-26 19:00:00Z",
        "limitedAmount":30,
        "countInfo":{
        "views":70,
        "likes":0,
        "liked":false,
        "type":"count_info"
        },
        "type":"special"
        },
        {
        "id":"1616636",
        "partnerId":3,
        "uuid":"57dacc36-abac-4bb3-89a4-f1981130b206",
        "type":"partner_offer"
        }
     ]
   }
}
```

FeedPojo.java

```
public class FeedPojo {

    private static String id;
    private static String businessId;
    private static String photoUrl;
    private static String videoUrl;
    public static String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public static void setId(String id) {
        FeedPojo.id = id;
    }

    public static String getPartnerId() {
        return partnerId;
    }

    public static void setPartnerId(String partnerId) {
        FeedPojo.partnerId = partnerId;
    }
   }
```

MainActivity.java

```
FeedPojo.setType(promoJsonObject.getString("type"));

Log.d(TAG, "TypeFeed:" + FeedPojo.getType());    
Log.e(TAG, "Type:" + promoJsonObject.getString("type"));    
             if (promoJsonObject.getString("type") == "news") {

                                        FeedPojo.setId(promoJsonObject.getString("id"));
                                        FeedPojo.setBusinessName(promoJsonObject.getString("businessName"));
                                        FeedPojo.setBusinessLogoUrl(promoJsonObject.getString("businessLogoUrl"));
                                        FeedPojo.setText(promoJsonObject.getString("text"));

 Log.d(TAG,"Id"+FeedPojo.getId());
                                        Log.d(TAG,"Businessname"+FeedPojo.getBusinessName());

                                    }
                                    if (FeedPojo.getType() == "special") {

                                        FeedPojo.setId(promoJsonObject.getString("id"));
                                        FeedPojo.setType(promoJsonObject.getString("type"));
                                        FeedPojo.setName(promoJsonObject.getString("name"));
                                        FeedPojo.setDescription(promoJsonObject.getString("description"));
                                        FeedPojo.setStart(promoJsonObject.getString("start"));
                                        FeedPojo.setEnd(promoJsonObject.getString("end"));
                }
```

Comment: Your FeedPojo does not seem to have all the fields.

Comment: I just posted only few fields just to make easy to understand.. But I declared all of them in my source code. @benjosantony

Answer (score 0):

We can parse like this,
FeedPojo.java

```
public class FeedPojo {
    int id;
    int businessId;
    int limitedAmount;
    int views;
    int likes;
    int partnerId;
    String photoUrl;
    String videoUrl;
    String type;
    String specialType;
    String name;
    String description;
    String start;
    String end;
    String countInfoType;
    String uuid;
    boolean isNew;
    boolean liked;
}
```

FeedParser.java

```
public class FeedParser {
    public static void parse(String response) {
        try {
            JSONObject feedObject = new JSONObject(response);

            if (feedObject == null) {
                return;
            }

            JSONArray feedArray = feedObject.optJSONArray("feed");

            if (feedArray == null) {
                return;
            }

            ArrayList<FeedPojo> feedPojos = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feed = feedArray.optJSONObject(i);

                if (feed == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                FeedPojo feedPojo = new FeedPojo();
                feedPojo.id = feed.optInt("id", 0);
                feedPojo.businessId = feed.optInt("businessId", 0);
                feedPojo.limitedAmount = feed.optInt("limitedAmount", 0);
                feedPojo.partnerId = feed.optInt("partnerId", 0);

                feedPojo.photoUrl = feed.optString("photoUrl", "");
                feedPojo.type = feed.optString("type", "");
                feedPojo.specialType = feed.optString("specialType", "");
                feedPojo.name = feed.optString("name", "");
                feedPojo.description = feed.optString("description", "");
                feedPojo.start = feed.optString("start", "");
                feedPojo.end = feed.optString("end", "");
                feedPojo.uuid = feed.optString("uuid", "");

                feedPojo.isNew = feed.optBoolean("isNew", false);
                feedPojo.isNew = feed.optBoolean("isNew", false);

                JSONObject countInfoObj = feed.optJSONObject("countInfo");

                if (countInfoObj == null) {

                    feedPojos.add(feedPojo);
                    continue;
                }

                feedPojo.views = countInfoObj.optInt("views", 0);
                feedPojo.likes = countInfoObj.optInt("likes", 0);
                feedPojo.liked = countInfoObj.optBoolean("liked", false);
                feedPojo.countInfoType = countInfoObj.optString("type", "");

                feedPojos.add(feedPojo);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Gson.

Gradle import:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
```

Code to parse our pojo with gson:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
Gson gson = new Gson();
FeedPojo feedPojo = gson.fromJson(object.toString(), FeedPojo.class);
```

Your FeedPojo must implement Serializable:

```
public class FeedPojo implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```